# Correct Grammatical Form for RMSE?

Tags: terminology, rms

Which is preferred for use in journal publication:  Root-Mean-Square Error or Root Mean Square**d** error?

Root-mean-square sounds a little casual, like "ice tea" instead of "iced." On the other hand, Cross-Validated's own tag uses just "square."

If there is a difference in usage across field, environmental science would be most relevant.

Comment: This is a fun question. My impression is that "root mean square error" is indeed somewhat colloquial, like "iff". Perhaps there are statistical writing guidelines out there somewhere that prescribe one form or the other. Failing that, it would be nice to see a journal editor pitch in.

Comment: Which community are you interested in?  Statisticians, mathematicians, engineers, psychologists, laypeople, social scientists, and so forth will vary in their preferences for one phrase or the other.

Comment: Environmental science.

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to ask a vague question like "what's preferred" without saying whose preferences you care about, and then appear to dismiss any answer you received as if people are somehow meant to infer some basis *other* than authority/popularity/reason. You asked for preferences, but almost every justification for offering someone's preference will be an informal fallacy - your question invites the very answers you appear to critique. If you don't wish to be seen as trolling you should probably reconsider  the current framing of your question and your comments.

Comment: A successful edit would at the least need to specify whose preferences you mean and given your comments on current answers, would also need to clearly explain how such preferences as you ask for could *NOT* also be regarded as some form of informal fallacy.

Comment: You are misreading dismissiveness or critique into what I find deeply interesting -- how we decide what's "right."  I upvoted them all; I think they are all good, and I am trying to decide which sort of argument sways me and others.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some textbook references:

- Page 546 of Ott and Longnecker says "recall that MS stands for mean square"
- Page 211 of DeGroot and Schervish (3rd edition) defines the mean square**d** error
- Page 30 of Draper and Smith (3rd edition) discusses the mean square.
- Page 158 of Draper and Smith, discusses MSE, which they call the residual mean square $s^2$.
- Page 202 of *elements of statistics and Probability* by Lippman defines mean square**d** error.

The two that mention the term RMSE directly, add the "d" at the end, but the others do not for the inner term mean square.

Comment: The appeal to authority . . .

Answer (score 6):

A google search of "*root mean square**d** error*" gives 318,000 results, while a search for "*root mean square error*" gives 1,660,000 results

A google scholar search of "*root mean square**d** error*" gives 61,300 results, while a search for "*root mean square error*" gives 224,000 results

I declare that "***root mean square error***" is preferred.

Comment: The appeal to popular opinion . . .

Answer (score 3):

It's *root mean square* because it's the root of the mean of squares, not the square of the root of the mean.

According to the [Merriam-Webster's](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/root%20mean%20square):

> **root–mean–square**:  the square root of the arithmetic mean of the squares of a set of numbers

For a similar parameter, the International Electrotechnical Commission (IEC), in its [Online Electrotechnical Vocabulary](http://www.electropedia.org/), suggests [root-mean-square](http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=103-02-02) too.

[Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=root+mean+square%2Croot+mean+squared&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Croot%20mean%20square%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Croot%20mean%20squared%3B%2Cc0) confirms the predominance of root mean square ([also with error](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=root+mean+square+error%2Croot+mean+squared+error&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Croot%20mean%20square%20error%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Croot%20mean%20squared%20error%3B%2Cc0)).

Comment: The appeal to reason . . .

Comment: Interesting points.  However, your argument is out of context: the full phrase is "root mean square[d] error."  That clearly indicates a squared error, not a square root mean.  It bothers some people that "squared error" is grammatical whereas "square error" is a little suspicious. It may be of interest that the use of "squared" in this context has increased 12-fold since 1970 whereas the use of "square" has only tripled: http://tinyurl.com/zmld8yg

Comment: @whuber The ambiguity comes from the fact that we get an error by squaring errors, but it happens also with the RMS value: it's a value obtained from squaring values, but root mean squared value is even rarer than root mean squared error. So, as I understand it, the indented parsing is probably ((root-mean-square) error), and not (root-mean (squared-errors)).

Comment: The latter is what a native English speaker would normally assume: adjectives tend to apply in a right-associative manner, preceding the noun. Thus, it would be natural for a grammatically consistent individual to use *both* the phrases "root mean squared error" and "root mean square" (as a noun phrase).

Comment: @whuber In my interpretation _value_ and, similarly, _error_ are instead the main nouns and _root-mean-square_ is a noun modifier, and together they form a compound noun. Mm... we will eventually discover that both interpretations are fine :-)